# bootstrap carousel does not work correctly using ng-view files angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am new to bootstrap and AngularJs. I am using bootstrap and Angular Js for my current application. When I use the bootstrap carousel directly inside the index page, the carousel's slide link are working absolutely perfect. But When I load the carousel markup through the second files using ng-view, the slide links does not work correctly. It only works one time and then just don't work the next time. Where I am going wrong. I am pasting the code below:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide myslider" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/d.jpg" alt="d1" class="center-block">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/c2.jpg" alt="c2" class="center-block">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/b.jpg" alt="b3" class="center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/a.jpg" alt="a4" class="center-block">
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors generated in the web browser's console?

Comment: no but when i click on the navigation buttons of carousel then ng-view is called and load the hall page and the in carousel first image is automatically appears.